# Invitation to visit university for PhD

Tags: phd, university, interview, visiting, sweden

Recently, I have been interviewed for swedish phd and I have gone through several skype interviews and  writing task. They have send me an email that I am a strong candidate. Now they are asking for visit the university for couple of days and see the laboratories. 
Since I am a foriegn national, they will paid all my travel expenses and etc. I am wonder why they are doing this? Have they intrested in offering phd for me?

Anyone have same experience?

Comment: Closely related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84241/potential-advisor-offering-to-fund-visit-to-lab

Answer (score 5):

Yes they are interested otherwise you won’t be invited. The is fairly normal procedure; some institutes interview candidates in person. I believe the goal for such visit is to set your expectations clear, meet with advisor before official acceptance, and to see where you would live in the next couple of years.

The best thing is to ask them what they expect from you during the visit.